# Can this animation not spam?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, styles

I am pretty new to xaml and wpf in general, so excuse me if the solution is easy or the xaml i used is bad. I am unsure if this is possible, but if there is some kind of solution please let me know!
Here is a video of what i am trying to fix:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z0Oe.jpg

If the video doesn't explain my problem, here it is: can the button animation not spam or bug when the user moves his cursor very fast across the button?

Here is the xaml for the animation:

```
 <Style x:Key="SlidingButtonToRight" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="270"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
            <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ClipToBounds" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Button.RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="110"   Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="110" To="0"  Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="SlidingButtonToLeft" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource SlidingButtonToRight}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="0" To="-110"  Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="-110" To="0"  Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Here is the xaml for the button on which i use the animation style:

```
<Button x:Name="button4" Click="Button4_Click" Style="{DynamicResource SlidingButtonToLeft}" Margin="0,50,-186,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/programm-bt.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
        <TextBlock Text="Programm" TextAlignment="Left" Width="105" Margin="0,0,-25,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, by removing **From** ,the animation doesn't start from 0 every time the user hovers over the button. Here is a video from [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z0Oe.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0cYo.jpg) the change.

```
 <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                 To="110"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                 />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                 To="0"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the animation spam, you can set a `BeginTime` property on your `MouseLeave` animation to give the user enough time to move the mouse off the button before the animation starts.

You can start with .2 seconds and tweak from there:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation
        BeginTime="0:0:0.2"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
        From="-110"
        To="0"
        Duration="0:0:0.3" />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: I think i found a solution: remove the <From> so that the animation doesn't start from 0 everytime the user hovers over it.Here is a  [video](https://imgur.com/a/NXU5aRT)